# PHP_XLSXWriter muti-lines header issue

Tags: php, der

I try to create with PHP_XLSXWriter an excel file having 2 header (text) lines and numeric values in the following lines.
I manage to create from php a file having 1 header line with expected types and styles for heder line and following data lines. This can be open in excel correctly.
When I insert from php a second header line (text) with writeSheetRow method, excel displays an warning/error message and suggests to repair the file.
When I accept the file to be repaired, file content is then ok (header (2 lines) and numeric data).
After saving the file, there is no more warning message when opening the file.
Does anybody knows a way to proceed in order to avoid the initiel warning message?
Thanks.

More details:
The issue is due to the fact that comumns types are defined when writing the header (row 1, with writeSheetHeader method). This determine the column's types of all following lines (from row 2 to ..). In my case row 2 is not a data line. It contains only strings that are second header line. This cause the problem because there is a conflict between the type defined in the header (numeric) and the actual values in the line (sring).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do. Show us the code you've all ready done - tried, and expected output would be useful. Spend some more time asking a question instead of writing roughly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by creating a modified version of writeSheetRow method that I named : writeSheetRowHeader.
In tthis new method I force the the type of the values inserted through this method to 'GENRAL'.

Insted of :

```
public function writeSheetRow($sheet_name, array $row, $row_options=null)
{
    ....
        $c=0;
        foreach ($row as $v) {
            $number_format = $sheet->columns[$c]['number_format']; //BEFORE
            $number_format_type = $sheet->columns[$c]['number_format_type']; //BEFORE
            $cell_style_idx = empty($style) ? $sheet->columns[$c]['default_cell_style'] : $this->addCellStyle( $number_format, json_encode(isset($style[0]) ? $style[$c] : $style) );
            $this->writeCell($sheet->file_writer, $sheet->row_count, $c, $v, $number_format_type, $cell_style_idx);
            $c++;
        }
.....
}
```

I use

```
public function writeSheetRowHeader($sheet_name, array $row, $row_options=null)
{
    ....
        $c=0;
        foreach ($row as $v) {
            $number_format = 'GENERAL'; // AFTER
            $number_format_type = 'n_auto'; // AFTER
            $cell_style_idx = empty($style) ? $sheet->columns[$c]['default_cell_style'] : $this->addCellStyle( $number_format, json_encode(isset($style[0]) ? $style[$c] : $style) );
            $this->writeCell($sheet->file_writer, $sheet->row_count, $c, $v, $number_format_type, $cell_style_idx);
            $c++;
        }
.....
}
```